# get integer value from NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, nsinteger

This in the function which i am implementing

```
-(NSString *)DeleteFolder:(NSInteger)FolderId;
```

In my implementation, I am creating string using `FolderId`

```
NSString *dbScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delete from Folders Where FolderId = %d",FolderId];
```

but I am not getting FolderId , instead of folder ID i am getting a very long integer value. Might be pointer reference.

Please tell me how to get folder id. Am I doing any thing wrong?

Comment: Did you not see a compiler warning? `values of type 'NSInteger' should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'long' instead [-Wformat].`

Answer (score 4):

`NSInteger` is not a portable type in the sense that you can never know if it's defined to `int`, `long`, `long long` or something else. So, the `%d` conversion specifier, which is exclusively for `int`, is not suited for printing an `NSInteger`. More precisely, its usage will result in undefined behavior. You will need to do an explicit typecast:

```
NSLog(@"Folder ID: %lld", (long long)FolderID);
```

(I used `long long` because that's the longest possible standard integer type.)

Comment: A cast to `long` is actually sufficient, `NSInteger` is either `int` (on 32-bit) or `long` (on 64-bit).

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:-

```
NSInteger a=20;
NSLog(@"yourInteger=%ld",(long)a);
```